# Slot doesn't render well on child component VueJS

Tags: vue.js, slot, v-for

I'm trying to loop over a component, I fill up slot with some data but they are not rendering well.

Weird behaviors :

- Data are displayed but not visible.
- In chrome if i toggle the `device toolbar` in the debug panel, data are now visible.
- Changing font-size in the debug panel make my data visible
- When i put a Child component outside the loop, the looped ones are rendered well.

Snippet from my parent Component :

```
<li class="cards__item" v-for="(staffMember, index) in staff">
   <card-profil>
       <h3 slot="title">{{staffMember.name}}</h3>
   </card-profil>
</li>
```

Snippet from my child Component :

```
<template>
    <section class="card-profil">
        <figure class="fig-card-profil">
            <figcaption class="figcaption-card-profil">
                <slot name="title"></slot>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
</template>
```

I get my data this way in my parent component:

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            staff: []
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.getStaff()
    },
    methods: {
        getStaff: async function () {
            const staff = await axios({ url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=8' })
            this.staff = staff.data.results
        }
      }
    }
```

Is this problem of lifehook ? Do i have to use Scoped slot instead ? V-for issue ?
Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Are you sure that is not CSS issue or something like that, because It renders here in the DOM pretty fine http://jsbin.com/qigoyojihe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the jsbin @BelminBedak. It's not a css issue i guarantee it. I just test a child component out of the loop and everything works fine..

Comment: No difficulty rendering it as well. https://jsfiddle.net/xkrmkkxv/ Your problem is outside of the provided sample.

Comment: Weird i don't know what could be the problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's something CSS if you can see the items rendered in DOM via Inspector.
Does console maybe yelling at you ?

Comment: `staffMember.name` is an object that contains the `first`, `last`and `title`keys.
Try the following: `staffMember.name.first` and see if it prints something.
https://jsbin.com/xasufey/edit?html,js,output